VBA Excel looping around offset cells
I have the situation such as this:
dws.Range("E5") = bws.Cells(jr, "AB").Value
dws.Range("E6") = bws.Cells(jr, "AC").Value
dws.Range("E7") = bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Value
dws.Range("E8") = bws.Cells(jr, "AE").Value

dws.Range("E9") = bws.Cells(jr, "AB").Offset(1, 0).Value
dws.Range("E10") = bws.Cells(jr, "AC").Offset(1, 0).Value
dws.Range("E11") = bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Offset(1, 0).Value
dws.Range("E12") = bws.Cells(jr, "AE").Offset(1, 0).Value

If bws.Cells(jr, "V").Offset(2, 0).Value = "S4-03" Then
dws.Range("E13") = bws.Cells(jr, "AB").Offset(2, 0).Value
dws.Range("E14") = bws.Cells(jr, "AC").Offset(2, 0).Value
dws.Range("E15") = bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Offset(2, 0).Value
dws.Range("E16") = bws.Cells(jr, "AE").Offset(2, 0).Value
End If

If bws.Cells(jr, "V").Offset(3, 0).Value = "S4-04" Then
dws.Range("E17") = bws.Cells(jr, "AB").Offset(3, 0).Value
dws.Range("E18") = bws.Cells(jr, "AC").Offset(3, 0).Value
dws.Range("E19") = bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Offset(3, 0).Value
dws.Range("E20") = bws.Cells(jr, "AE").Offset(3, 0).Value
End If

If bws.Cells(jr, "V").Offset(4, 0).Value = "S4-05" Then
dws.Range("E21") = bws.Cells(jr, "AB").Offset(4, 0).Value
dws.Range("E22") = bws.Cells(jr, "AC").Offset(4, 0).Value
dws.Range("E23") = bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Offset(4, 0).Value
dws.Range("E24") = bws.Cells(jr, "AE").Offset(4, 0).Value
End If


In column U, I have objects, to which various rows are assigned. They're divided by thick lines as you can see above.
Basically, if value S4-01, values from columns Ab to AE are picked up from the same row. If value S4-02 is observed in column V, then values come from the same columns but row below.
I used the offset for it, although because I might have 12 IF cases (S4-01 to S4-12) it's quite tedious to change them all.
Is there any way to make a loop within them?

It would be useful to see the column headers so we can be certain which column is U. The expected result would also be useful. This may be possible to do with a lookup or an index/match formula

It is not obvious what the logic here is intended to do but the regularity of the actions suggests that it could be wrapped in a for loop as follows:
For i = 0 To 4
   If bws.Cells(jr, "V").Offset(i, 0).Value = "S4-0" & i+1 Then
      dws.Range("E" & 5+4*i) = bws.Cells(jr, "AB").Offset(i, 0).Value
      dws.Range("E" & 6+4*i) = bws.Cells(jr, "AC").Offset(i, 0).Value
      dws.Range("E" & 7+4*i) = bws.Cells(jr, "AD").Offset(i, 0).Value
      dws.Range("E" & 8+4*i) = bws.Cells(jr, "AE").Offset(i, 0).Value
   End If
Next i

Use with caution it may not quite do what you want but it should be adjustable (untested). You might want to have the prefix string "S4" and the number of times to apply it as parameters to any subroutine you create.

Maybe change "S4-0" & i+1 to "S4-" & Format(i + 1, "00") to accommodate numbers up to 99..?

@CLR fair point.  He did say it could go up to 12. Thanks.

I guess that OP tries to transpose the data. The target row should be changed otherwise the data of BE03AD overwrites BE03AA.
Using Resize to change shape of the range, the code could assign/copy values for multiple cells.
Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)

Sub Demo()
    Dim dws As Worksheet, bws As Worksheet
    Dim iR As Long, jr As Long
    Const START_ROW_DWS = 5
    Const START_ROW_BWS = 2
    Set bws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    iR = START_ROW_DWS
    For jr = START_ROW_BWS To bws.Cells(bws.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
        dws.Cells(iR, "E").Resize(4, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(bws.Cells(jr, "AB").Resize(1, 4).Value)
        iR = iR + 4
    Next
End Sub


